# How to set SMTP Enrcyption with an environment variable

Tags: craft3, emails, settings, environmentvariables

The official Craft documentation says it is possible to set the "Encryption Method (SMTP)" , [Snipped from the documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCGhk.png), with an Environment Variable.

I think i am missing something but i cant seem to find the exact .env Variable Name Craft is expecting for this setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can name the environment variable whatever you want. The trick is that the variable's ***value*** needs to be either `none`, `ssl` or `tls` (i.e. the three options that are supported for the "Encryption Method" setting), for it to be selectable for that setting.

For example, if you add a variable called `SMTP_ENCRYPTION_METHOD` to your `.env` file, and set its value to `ssl` (i.e. `SMTP_ENCRYPTION_METHOD=ssl`), that variable will show up as a selectable option for the "Encryption Method" setting:

[image]

Note that the "Use authentication" setting has the same behaviour; any and all environment variables with a *value* set to one of these settings' supported options (`yes`, `no`, `true`, `false`, `on`, `off`, `0` or `1`, for the "Use authentication" setting) will be selectable, regardless of the actual variable name.

**Edit:** Environment variable support for the Encryption Method setting was only added in [Craft 3.7.22](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md#3722---2021-11-23), so make sure you're on at least that version.

Comment: Where can one find all the possible environment variables related to SMTP in craft?

Comment: @BrokenCode Anything in particular you're looking for? There aren't any dedicated environment variables related to SMTP per se; only environment variable _support_ for most of the SMTP settings. The actual environment variables can be named anything.

Answer (score 1):

In the CP, I don't think that's an option. The name of the variable is encryptionMethod and its value comes from database (encryptionMethod). It doesn't have an accessible value from your .env file.

In your PHP code yes you can do that. You will just have to use `Craft::parseEnv($yourVariable);`

Comment: It was added quite recently in [Craft 3.7.22](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md#3722---2021-11-23) :)

Comment: No wonder! I guess I need to update. Dev is running 3.6.18. And thank you for that!

Comment: Added a note about that to the my answer, since it's so recent – OP might be on an older version, too :)